# SCTP Multihoming INIT messages

Tags: sctp

In a SCTP multihoming configuration, I have configured two sets - primary and secondary paths. My question is where is the INIT command sent by default on primary or secondary (assuming both the paths are up )?
Is there any condition that the INIT needs to be sent on primary path only if it is in UP state ?

Answer (score 0):

Any SCTP packet, by default should be sent using primary path. This is what i found in RFC 4960 - Sec:6.4 - Para:III

```
By default, an endpoint SHOULD always transmit to the primary path,
unless the SCTP user explicitly specifies the destination transport
address (and possibly source transport address) to use.
```

Regarding second question - "Is there any condition that the INIT needs to be sent on primary path only if it is in UP state ?"

It does not look logical to send via an interface which is down. Below is the RFC 4960 - Sec:6.4.1 - Para:II

```
When there is outbound data to send and the primary path becomes
inactive (e.g., due to failures), or where the SCTP user explicitly
requests to send data to an inactive destination transport address,
before reporting an error to its ULP, the SCTP endpoint should try to
send the data to an alternate active destination transport address if
one exists.
```